# Not able to access angular element inside React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, ecmascript-6, web-component

I have create an Angular element like below :

```html
import { inject, Injector, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private _injector: Injector) {
    const element = createCustomElement(AppComponent, {
      injector: this._injector,
    });
    customElements.define('NewsWidget', element);
  }

  ngDoBootstrap() {}
}
```

And i am using the same in my react app by making below changes.

In index.html I have added script source as

```html
  <script src="../../../../Angular/news-custom-element/news-dist/news-custom-element.js"></script>
```

Also , i have tried adding same path in App.tsx as

```js
import './App.css';
import UploadButton from './Component/UploadButton';
import { GlobalContextProvider } from './Context/globalContext';
import MessageComponent from './Shared/Alert';
import '../../../../Angular/news-custom-element/news-dist/news-custom-element';

function App() {

  return (
    <GlobalContextProvider>
      <NewsWidget></NewsWidget>
      <UploadButton />
      <MessageComponent />
    </GlobalContextProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But i am keep getting the error as

[image]

Any help would be appreciated here

Comment: have you tried doing `ng build --prod --output-hashing none`. This will create a `dist/NewsWidget` folder that you can use to integrate with React

Comment: Already done that and path in index.html refers to same folder only.